# Filter out undefined inside a loop with find

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

If I remove a `div id` from the loop, I get an undefined.

**HTML:**

For argument sake, this is a loop (twice)

```
<div class="card">
 <canvas class="chart-class" id="chart_<%=model.id%>" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
<div>
<div class="card">
 <% if 1 == 2 %>
   <canvas class="chart-class" id="chart_<%=model.id%>" width="400" height="200">
 <% else %>
   No chart to display
 <% end %>
<div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.card').each(function() {
  let demo =  $(this).find('.foo').attr('id');
  console.log(demo);
});
```

This will give me the id numbers. If I remove div with id 1 or 2, I get `undefined` in console, but do get the last id number. I need to prevent that:

```
$('.card').filter(undefined, function() {...});
```

Nothing shows. How to go about this?

Edit:

I'm displaying a [cart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) in place of the above `div class="foo"`. I do have two loops but most times only one chart will be present. In my js:

```
$('.card').each(function() {
 let chartId = $(this).find('.chart-class').attr('id');
 let ctx =  $(`#${chartId}`);

  [// chart data]
});
```

Comment: are you finding after dom is loaded?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Ok, I'll get precise. Let me update post.

Comment: "If I remove div with id 1 or 2": show us that code; in other words provide a complete example.

Comment: @JeroenHeier There you go, in rails.

Comment: Are you trying to get .card that contains a .foo with id?

Comment: @Darlesson So sorry. I've made complete change. See edit

Comment: It seems to me you need `$('.card > .foo[id]');`

Comment: The issue is, im looping on the div and when it cant find a canvas, it gives undefined. I need a way to make it loop x amount of times a canvas is present. I'll have a deeper look later.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.card').each(function() {    

    let demo =  $(this).find('.foo');

    if(demo.length){
        console.log(demo.attr('id'));
    }
}
```

If it finds the element with the class name of `foo`, it will try to get the `id` attribute, if not, it will skip that element and wont return `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to check for undefined you need to write

```
typeof blah == 'undefined'
```

Secondly, I'm not entirely sure what you're desired affect is, but you could use something like below

```
$('.card').each(function(){
         var fooId = ....find foo id;
          if (typeof fooId != 'undefined') {
              console.log(fooId);
          }
  });
```